# Computed column value not the same as Scalar Function it uses

Tags: sql-server, sql-function, calculated-columns

I have a Table with a computed column that uses a scalar function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertToMillimetres]
(
    @fromUnitOfMeasure int,
    @value decimal(18,4)
)
RETURNS decimal(18,2)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    CASE 
        WHEN @fromUnitOfMeasure=1 THEN @value
        WHEN @fromUnitOfMeasure=2 THEN @value * 100
        WHEN @fromUnitOfMeasure=3 THEN @value * 1000
        WHEN @fromUnitOfMeasure=4 THEN @value * 25.4
     ELSE @value
    END
END

GO
```

The table has this column

```
[LengthInMm]  AS (CONVERT([decimal](18,2),[dbo].[ConvertToMillimetres]([LengthUnitOfMeasure],[Length]))) PERSISTED,
```

Assuming that the [Length] on the Table is 62.01249 and [LengthUnitOfMeasure] is 4 the LengthInMm computed value comes with 1575.11 but when i run the function directly like

```
SELECT [dbo].[ConvertToMillimetres] (4, 62.01249) GO
```

It comes with 1575.12

[Length] column is (decimal(18,4, null))

Can anyone tell why this happens?

Comment: Please share the data type of the `[Length]` column with us.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry. [Length] is (decimal(18,4),null)

Comment: Please run the following query (filtered to the problematic record) and share the result with us: SELECT [Length] FROM [YourTable]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this really counts as an answer, but you've perhaps got a problem with a specific version of SQL?

I just had a go at replicating it (on a local SQL 2014 install) and got the following:

```
create table dbo.Widgets (
  Name varchar(20),
  Length decimal(18,4),
  LengthInMm AS [dbo].[ConvertToMillimetres] (4, Length) PERSISTED
)

insert into dbo.Widgets (Name, Length) values ('Thingy', 62.01249)

select * from dbo.Widgets
```

Which gives the result:

```
Name                 Length                                  LengthInMm
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
Thingy               62.0125                                 1575.12

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Note that your definition uses `[LengthInMm]  AS (CONVERT([decimal](18,2),[dbo].[ConvertToMillimetres]([LengthUnitOfMeasure],[Length]))) PERSISTED`, but that doesn't seem to make a difference to the result.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried on my PC (Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)). Works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.data(
    LengthUnitOfMeasure INT,
    [Length] decimal(18,4),
    [LengthInMm] AS (CONVERT([decimal](18,2),[dbo].[ConvertToMillimetres]([LengthUnitOfMeasure],[Length]))) PERSISTED
)


INSERT INTO dbo.data (LengthUnitOfMeasure, [Length])
SELECT 4, 62.01249

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.data

/*
RESULT
LengthUnitOfMeasure Length  LengthInMm
4                   62.0125 1575.12
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the answer:

Lets see what you are saying:

There is a column with `decimal(18,4)` data type.
There is a calculated column which depend on this column.
The result differs when you select the calculated field and when you provide the *same* result manually. (Right?)

Sorry, but the input parameters are not the same:
The column in the table is `decimal(18,4)`. The value you are provided manually is `decimal(7,5)` (62.01249)

Since the column in the table can not store any values with scale of 5, the provided values will not be equal. (Furthermore there is no record in the table with the value of `62.01249` in the `Length` column)

What is the output when you query the `[Length]` column from the table? Is it `62.0124`? If yes, then this is the answer. The results can not be equal since the input values are not equal.

To be a bit more specific: `62.01249` will be casted (implicit cast) to `62.0125`.

```
ROUND(25.4 * 62.0124, 2) = 1575.11
ROUND(25.4 * 62.0125, 2) = 1575.12
```

**EDIT** Everybody who tried to rebuild the schema made the same mistake (Including me). When we (blindly) inserted the values from the original question into our instances, we inserted the `62.01249` into the `Length` column -> the same implicit cast occured, so we have the value `62.0125` in our tables.

Comment: not true. When first I inserted into table 62.01249 it made 62.0125 count. So when I created computed column it gave also 1575.12.

Comment: That's what I said. Implicit cast occurred. I think the OP's db contains a truncated value (6.0124), and our db contains a rounded value (62.0125). The OP, or their client program truncated the original value during insert.

Comment: He has a calculated column, which implies that he has a table and one or more column to do the calculation. He can check the value in the table. If it is truncated - and the truncation is not expected - than he possibly can check the client program. If not, then he can open a ticket fot the client program's vendor. (And if he truncated the value during an initial load, then he can do anything what he want).